# How to solve this integral involving Bessel function.

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I need some help in solving this integration:

$\int_0^{\gamma_t}K_0\left(2\sqrt{\frac{x}{a^2b^2c^2e}}\right)\text{d}x$

where, $K_0$ is modified Bessel function of second kind, $a,b,c,e$ are all constants.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried replacing all the constants with one arbitrary constant and using the definition of the Bessel function? Maybe then try to switch the order of integration? I’m not sure it will help but it’s a start

Comment: Yes ...I tried this but not getting it. Also, I checked gradshteyn table of integrals series and products but closed form expression is not available....

Comment: I really doubt a closed form expression is available, but by adding more details to your question and showing your work you can get more people to help you. I'd recommend including more details of your objectives as well: your motivation, what is $\gamma_t$ supposed to be, what approximation error are you OK with, if you need a series approximation or not, etc.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_0^{\gamma t}{K_0}\left( 2\sqrt{\frac{x}{a^2b^2c^2e}} \right) \mathrm{d}x
\\
x=\frac{a^2b^2c^2eu^2}{4},=\frac{a^2b^2c^2e}{2}\int_0^{\frac{2\sqrt{\gamma t}}{abc\sqrt{e}}}{uK_0}\left( u \right) \mathrm{d}u
\\
=\frac{a^2b^2c^2e}{2}uK_1\left( u \right) |_{0}^{\frac{2\sqrt{\gamma t}}{abc\sqrt{e}}}
\\
=abc\sqrt{e\gamma t}K_1\left( \frac{2\sqrt{\gamma t}}{abc\sqrt{e}} \right) 
$$

Comment: Ok....can you please elaborate about how you solve this integration....